# Configure ReportServerTempDB and ReportServer databases with multiple data files for better performance?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2019

Is there any way for "ReportServerTempDB" or "ReportServer" Database to configure with multi data files?

As best practices dictate that one TempDB data file be created for each CPU core on the server, up to a maximum of 8 data files, So same way is there any way for "ReportServerTempDB" or "ReportServer" database?

Comment: Whats stopping you increasing the temp db data files for SSTS the same as you would any other database?

Comment: The recommendation for tempdb is due to how tempdb is used.  The possibility of page contention on GAM, SGAM or PFS pages can be reduced or eliminated by having multiple data files.  The same doesn't apply to user databases so there is no reason to split user database files to multiple files.  To get any type of performance benefit (and it is unlikely to do so) - you would need separate volumes for each file at a minimum.  And even then, since all traffic is going through the same channels on the HBA - it is unlikely you will see any performance benefit.